# Dynamic child component injection in Angular component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm working on chat application in Ionic and Angular (typescript) which lets users to use [spoiler][/spoiler] tags in their messages to mark some text as potential spoiler, e.g. "blah blah [spoiler]spoiled blah[/spoiler]". Now when receiving such message in my application I need to replace that spoiler with button that will reveal hidden message when clicked and that button should appear in this specific place in a message. The messages are stored in an array and that array of messages is presented in component using ngFor. Every incoming message is simply added to that array.

My first attempt at solving this was to simply replace part of a string message with html block such as `<button (click)="revealSpoiler()">Spoiler</button>` and use `[InnerHTML]` in template to show that added html (using declared Pipe to allow safe HTML of course). This way, the button is being shown in my component, but event is not working. I found a way to fix this with simply adding event listener using `ElementRef` but it feels hacky and even more hacky if you realize that there can be more than one such spoiler, so now to track them I would have to use some incrementing variable as id.

So I tried injecting it as component. I created SpoilerChild as follows

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'spoiler',
  template: `<button *ngIf="isHidden; else reveal" (click)="revealSpoiler()">Spoiler</button>
              <ng-template #reveal>{{msg}}</ng-template>`
})
export class SpoilerChild {
  @Input() msg: string;
  isHidden: boolean = true;

  constructor() {
  }

  private revealSpoiler() {
    this.isHidden = false;
  }
}
```

and then rather than replacing [spoiler][/spoiler] with button block, I used `<spoiler [msg]="spoilerPart"></spoiler>`, where `spoilerPart` is the message to be revealed. But in this approach the selector is not replaced with desired component (I believe Angular does not resolve this at runtime).

I thought about using ComponentFactoryResolver, but in all examples I found this approach relies on class variable declaration such as

```
@ViewChild('spoiler', { read: ViewContainerRef }) spoiler:ViewContainerRef;
```

But in my case I don't have that spoiler selector in my template, because it is added in case specific message is received from observable.

So my question is: can I somehow inject my child component when the place for injection is not known at initialization? Or is there maybe some better solution to my problem, which is also recommended way of doing such thing in angular architecture?

Comment: You want insert dynamically a component?

Comment: Yes, I think I made that clear in my question. The problem is the place for insertion is not initially known, because the incoming message can be like "blah blah [spoiler]spoiled blah[/spoiler]" and i have to insert my child component in place of those spoiler tags. If something is unclear, please ask more specific question.

Comment: I edited my post adding closing quotation that was missing in template code, but it was just a typo i made writting this post, it is correct in my app code.

Comment: I think this [link from Angular's doc](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) might help implement what you're looking for. Let me know if the doc makes sense to you or not.

Comment: @UnsinkableSam I've seen this example earlier and it almost fits my scenario, except one thing. This example uses `<ng-template ad-host></ng-template>` tag that is initially placed in component's template and loads dynamic component into this tag. They also make a reference to it as `@ViewChild(AdDirective) adHost: AdDirective;`. In my case, I don't have this static tag in template, because it can appear only in case incoming message has [spoiler][/spoiler] tag, (which I tried replacing with template on the fly but it's not automatically resolved so I'm left with empty tag in my HTML).

Comment: If you is using Angular 4 you can to try ngComponentOutlet directive, it is for inserts dinamically components, https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet